# Lanchester's war model optimization.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Suppose the Lanchester's war model:

$f'(t)=-0.5g(t)+x\sin^2(t)$

$g'(t)=-0.5f(t)+\cos^2(t)$

with $f(0)=g(0)=2$.

How to estimate how small $x$ can be in order to make $f(t)$ won't reach $0$ on the interval $[0,15]$?

By using mathematica, it's easy to solve the equations with a constant number instead of a variable $x$. But how to optimize $x$?

Comment: I think $x$ is a parameter.

Comment: $x$ is an variable. I need to find the smallest value of $x$ that $f(t)$ won't reach $0$ when $t \leq 15$. Because the smaller value the $x$ is, the faster $f(t)$ goes to $0$.

Comment: The question is, is $x$ a variable which depends on $t$, or may $x$ be set independently of $t$?  If the latter holds, then the equation falls in the normal purview of ODEs with parameters.  If not, we need to know some equation which governs $x(t)$.  Otherwise, the function $x(t)$ is arbitrary and virtually anything can happen.  Indeed, it $x$ depends on $t$, it is not even clear that forcing $x(t)$ small, say $\vert x(t) \vert < \epsilon$, will have the desired effect!

Comment: @Amzoti:  there you go disappearing again!  You're worse than Bilbo with that infernal ring of his (well, Sauron's)! ;-)

Comment: $x$ is independent. So, we cannot find the optimize it with an independent variable $x$? $f'(t)$ increases as $x$ increases. I think we could find the smallest $x$ that $f(t)$ decreases slowly enough to make it stay greater than $0$ until $t=15$.

Comment: I've tried with several value of $x$ and found that when $x=2.08895$, $f(15)=0.0004$ which I can conclude that the smallest $x$ should be a little bit greater than $2.08895$.